# Configurar a biblioteca Jackson para atributos dinâmicos

Tags: java, json, jackson

Estou usando a biblioteca Jackson para transformar o seguinte JSON em um objeto Java.

```
{"name":"Agent/MetricsReported/count","begin":"2014-02-04T09:44:00Z","end":"2014-02-04T09:45:00Z","app":"","agent_id":, "average_exclusive_time":0.23999999463558197}
```

O meu problema é que todos os campos do JSON são fixos, exceto o último (`average_exclusive_time`). Ele pode ter outro nome de acordo com um parâmetro passado na requisição de um web service.

Há alguma forma de configurar a biblioteca Jackson para que ela mapeie este último valor dinâmico para um campo chamado `value` ou talvez para um `Map`.

O que eu quero evitar é ter que criar uma classe para cada variação possível deste último campo que pode assumir outros nomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a anotação [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonAnySetter.html) em um tipo se *setter* especial associado a um `Map`.

Segundo a própria documentação, o método com essa anotação servirá como um *fallback* quando um atributo não existir no *bean*, ou seja, os atributos existentes serão preenchidos normalmente e apenas os que o Jackson não encontrar serão encaminhados para o *setter* especial.

Use esta anotação em conjunto com `@JsonAnyGetter` para que o mapa também seja incluído na serialização do *bean* para Json.

Veja um exemplo de implementação a seguir:

```java
private Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<String,Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String,Object> values() {
    return values;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String key, Object value) {
    values.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo esta solução. Notei que se eu criar os setters dos outros atributos, ele só vai entrar no @JsonAnySetter para os atributos que não possuem setter.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição Isso mesmo. Eu melhorei a resposta para tentar deixar isso mais claro.